# Use case formulation

Tags: use-case

I was thinkering with the specs for a web service and this question popped into my head.

Should the following use case:

> - A user can vote on other users' posts 
>     so to modify the latters' reputation

be split into two use cases?

> - A user can vote other users' posts
> - When a user gets voted, her    reputation changes accordingly

Wich one is better formulated?

Comment: Well, there are to contrasting opinions. I'm waiting for a third one to choose which one to accept.

Comment: With the current information I think its personal preference, in order to get a definite answer there would have to be more information.  If you always want the two events to happen at the same time it keeps things simpler to keep them together.  However, if you want to be able to modify reputation without votes or if you want votes without modifying reputation the split method could work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for the split option, this way you have way more control over each process and it's also easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is a case where you want them to happen independently I can't think of a reason to split them.